# What is this mathematical symbol called?

Tags: notation

Could you please help me identify the following symbol? Some help on how to type it in $\LaTeX$ would also be really helpful.

$$\huge \mathcal{N}_i$$

Comment: \mathcal{N}_i should do it.

Comment: What do you mean by "identify"? What it means might depend exactly on the context. By the way, it is `\mathcal N_i` $\mathcal N_i$.

Comment: I thought it might be a named symbol at first (like a greek letter). But \mathcal does the trick. Thank you very much.

Comment: There is a LaTeX stackexchange also I think.

Comment: It's impossible to tell without context, but there's a chance it's alluding to this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aleph_number

Comment: Is the question just about identifying what that symbol is, or about what the symbol actually means in a mathematical context?

Comment: If you are strictly asking for the $\LaTeX$ and not about its usage or meaning in math, then this is off-topic here. On $\TeX$, I think they would tell you to [use Detexify](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14/how-to-look-up-a-symbol-or-identify-a-math-symbol-or-character).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the mathcal font:

`\mathcal{N}_{i}` produces 
$\mathcal{N}_{i}$

---

The symbol $\mathcal{N}$ in the context of linear algebra denotes a null space.

The alphabet in `\mathcal{}`:

$\mathcal{A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V}$